# SQL To delete characters from a column

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have a wordpress site. I want to delete the first 15 characters from every post on the site.

I believe the table is wp_posts, and the column is post_content

What would be the sql that I execute from my database manager?

Comment: What is your reasoning for wanting to remove this content?

Comment: the beginning of every post starts with a word, which is 15 characters long, and I want to remove it. The word sometimes also appears in the middle of the posts, but there i don't want to remove it. so instead of doing a search/replace I figured deleting the first 15 characters is most efficient.

Comment: Don't have the time right now to look up the database schema and run a test case to make sure an answer works, but a couple of points:1) When doing a potentially destructive DB change, it's a good idea to back up the data you might be destroying into a temp table.  Worst case scenario, it's unnecessary, and you can just drop the table, but it can save you a lot of headache if something goes wrong. 2) If you know what these leading characters are it may be safer to use `REPLACE()` rather than taking a substring as you'll only get the matching posts, and you'll be able to safely rerun the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = substr(post_content, 16);
```

[read more...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)

Comment: hi, I'm quite amateur with sql, do you mind rewriting that while calling on wp_posts and post_content ?

Comment: Just be careful to only run the script only once! Otherwise, you'll trim off the first 15*n characters (n = number of times the script is run).